# C - Read value from a specific memory address

Tags: c

How do I read a value from a given memory address (e.g. `0xfed8213`) using the C programming language?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each process has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), so, address `0x12345678` in one program will not be the same as address `0x12345678` in another.

You can access what is at the address simply by doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *ptr = (char *)0x12345678; //the addr you wish to access the contents of
    printf("%c\n", *ptr); //this will give you the first byte, you can add any more bytes you need to the ptr itself, like so: *(ptr + nbyte).

    return 0;
}
```

You'll likely get a segmentation fault though, unless you really know what you're doing. My guess is that you think this is the way to solve some other problem, whereas this isn't the actual solution. This does answer your question in the OP, though.

Here is [Another Virtual Memory learning resource.](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-intro.pdf)

Comment: For the memory address range, it should be something like 0x00000000 - 0xffffffff. Am I allowed to read a specific value in the range of this address ? If so, why I got the seg fault here ?

Comment: @user3815726 You get a seg fault if you're trying to read something for which you aren't mapped a page. I'd read the link I hyperlinked if you want to learn more about virtual memory, or check out an OS book. Just because that entire range is available, doesn't mean you have it all mapped to your process right away :)